# Firebase in node.js, set() callback is delayed

Tags: firebase

I have an EC2 instance running a small node script connecting to Firebase. Strangely enough, it happens quite often on a small instance that the set operation gets executed immeditely but the callback function only gets called much later (between 30s to 2 minutes). Do you see any reason why it would happen that way?

```
console.log('creating');

// Create workspace
rootRef.child('spaces').child(chid).set(req.space, function(error) {
  var end = new Date().getTime();
  var time = end - start;
  console.log('- created', error, time);
});
```

Comment: Hrm.  This is the second report we've gotten of this, and I'd love to track it down.  Unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce on my own EC2 instance.  Can you email me (michael at firebase dot com)?  Then I'll follow up with you to try to track down what's going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The bug is directly related to node 0.11 (set() callback is only called the first name in my scenario). Just revert to 0.10.x and it's all fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same issue. the "Set" callback is not being invoked at all. I noticed, however, that if I run a snippet code similar to yours in a standalone file, the callback is invoked very quickly.

It turned out that if you're installing listeners on the same Node you're calling the "set" function on (i.e., on('child_added'), on('child_removed') ... etc) and that Node has a huge number of records, it'll simply take ages.

I removed the listeners ( to test) and the "set" started to invoke the callback very quickly.

I hope this helps!